# get notified when result of useContractCall from useDapp arrives in react hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, usedapp

This is more a react question I think;

```
export function useData() {
    const [Data]: any = useContractCall({
        abi: myContractInterface,
        address: myContractAddress,
        method: "getAllData",
        args: [],
    }) ?? [];
    return Data;
}
let myData = useData();
<div>{myData ? myData.name : "no Data yet"}</div>
```

UseData() is called and the view is rendered when myData is propagated; but how could I use myData somewhere else in my logic? Tried with an async wrapper and await, didn't work.

I tried to use useEffect to listen on changes of myData and react, but useEffect is fired immediately and myData is null.

```
  let myData = useData();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Fresh Data is here",myData);//rotten undefined, not fresh data
  }, [myData ])
```

Should I just use something like this? I mean it is working.. but

```
const x = useData();

(async() => {
    console.log("waiting for variable");
    while(!x) // define the condition as you like
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    console.log("variable is defined",x);
})();
```

Comment: how `useContractCall` looks like?

Comment: @skyboyer https://github.com/EthWorks/useDApp/blob/c29ce02c3741f8acc1e6dff2e8893d6ab40f6e82/packages/core/src/hooks/useContractCall.ts

Comment: I edited my question and added a workaround..maybe that is it?

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to figure out whole the bunch of custom hooks calling each other. I have in the end some "last in the chain" hook does async request and after receiving response triggers re-render with new value in `const x`.

With this assumption, I want to say you don't need to

```
(async() => {
    console.log("waiting for variable");
    while(!x) // define the condition as you like
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    console.log("variable is defined",x);
})();
```

right in the render logic. Moreover it will never work. `const x = useData()` will never changed during this specific render execution. It will/may be re-assigned only on next re-render run.

Instead you should return some rendering result as if it is there. And it will be - initially `null`(by your words), but later component will re-render with actual data in `x`:

```
const x = useData();

....
return <SomeComponent prop={x} />
```

Also you should also see that with your

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Fresh Data is here",myData);
}, [myData])
```

As at first it prints `null` and later dumps actual data.

Once re-render does not happen as I described above - the issue is somewhere within your custom hooks. And you will need to debug that with debugger.